# How to put List in the Properties Window of visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, properties

I am working on a plugin in visual studio.
I want to put some properties in the Properties Window of Visual Stuido 2013.

I know how to put a string property in the window. For example:

```
    [Category(Info)]
    [DisplayName(@"Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "item.name";
        }
    }
```

But I need to put a List in one Category and show them in the properties window.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you be a bit more elaborate on this. Maybe it's just me, but I couldn't understand your question properly.

Comment: you may look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165403.aspx)